# React app - SEO metadata existing in inspect element but missing in page source

Tags: reactjs, optimization, seo, metadata, server-side-rendering

I added some logic to update meta description and title for every page in my React app, and it works correctly in app (when I inspect element, I can see correct data in  tag of index file) but when I open page source, it only shows initial index.html without any meta data and it makes problems for SEO optimization and crawlers. I know what's the problem, it's actually con of SPA app. Now the question, how can I prerender/set up metadata correctly in SPA app, if possible? Or the only solution is to rewrite the app in Next.js?
I tried npm lib `react-spa-prerenderer` but it generates static html files for every page, and when I crate production build and serve it locally, page sources miss metadata again (although generated html files for every page containt all metadata).

Comment: What do you mean by " although generated HTML files for every page contains all metadata"

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called "server-side rendering". Next.js is one, but not the only, way to render React on the server. Searching the internet for "react ssr" will give you many options and tutorials.